# How to find cumulative distribution function from probability measure?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, borel-sets, cumulative-distribution-functions

We define $P$ as the following:
$$P(B) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & (1,1), (-1, -1) \notin B \\
      \frac{1}{2} & (1,1) \in B, (-1, -1) \notin B \\
      \frac{1}{2} & (1,1) \notin B, (-1, -1) \in B \\
      1 & (1,1) \in B, (-1, -1) \in B \\ 
   \end{cases}
$$

Determine cdf for $P$.

Since this is in $R^2$ I know that I can use the cdf formula $F(x_{1}, x_{2}) = P((-\infty, x_{1}]\times(-\infty, x_{2}]).$

I also can see that you can plug in for the points $(1,1), (-1, -1)$ in the formula and break it up into disjoint sets. However, I don't see how this is the answer for the cdf.

$$F(x_{1},x_{2}) = \begin{cases} 
      0 &  x_{1} < -1, x_{2} < -1\\
      \frac{1}{2} &   -1\leq x_{1} < -1, -1\leq x_{2} < \infty \\
      \frac{1}{2} &   -1\leq x_{1} < \infty, -1\leq x_{2} < 1 \\
      1 &  x_{1} \geq 1,x_{2} \geq 1 \\ 
   \end{cases}
$$

Comment: Can you explain what this means,  $P[B=0]$ for $ (1,1), (-1, -1) \notin B$ and $P[B=1]$ for $(1,1) \notin B, (-1, -1) \notin B $ ?  Is this a typo or intended?

Comment: @GwendolynAnderson Not a typo this is how the exercise was presented.

Comment: Should the first line be $\in B$?  Or should the last line be both $\in B$?  Can you explain what it means - the first line and the last line?

Comment: @GwendolynAnderson My bad didn't catch that. I have fixed it now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> $$\def\<{\langle}\def\>{\rangle} P(B) = \begin{cases} 
>       0 & \<1,1\>\notin B, \<-1, -1\> \notin B \\
>       \frac{1}{2} & \<1,1\> \in B, \<-1, -1\> \notin B \\
>       \frac{1}{2} & \<1,1\> \notin B, \<-1, -1\> \in B \\
>       1 & \<1,1\> \in B, \<-1, -1\> \in B \\ 
>    \end{cases}$$

So you wish to define $F(x_1,x_2) := P((-\infty..x_1]\times(-\infty..x_2])$.

For example, $F(0,0)=P((-\infty..0]\times (-\infty..0])$, thus $F(0,0)=1/2$ because $\<-1,-1\>$ is in the interval, but $\<1,1\>$ is not.

Let us study the cases:

- $\<-1,-1\>$ will be in the interval exactly when *both* $x_1,x_2$ are at least $-1$.
- $\<1,1\>$ will be in the interval when *both*  $x_1,x_2$ are at least $1$.

  - So, if both  $x_1,x_2$ are at least $-1$ but at least one among them is less than $1$, then $\<-1,-1\>$ will be in the interval, but $\<1,1\>$ will not.  This occurs when $(-1\leq x_1< 1\land -1\leq x_2)\lor(1\leq x_1\land -1\leq x_2< 1)$.

Hence we have:

$$F(x_{1},x_{2}) = \begin{cases} 
      0 &:&  \qquad ~~x_1<-1 &\lor& \qquad ~~x_{2} <-1\\
      \frac{1}{2} &:&   -1\leq x_1< 1&,& -1\leq x_{2} \\
      \frac{1}{2} &:&   ~~~1\leq x_{1} &,& -1\leq x_{2} < 1 \\
      1 &:&  ~~~1\leq x_{1}&,& ~~~1\leq x_{2} 
   \end{cases}
$$